# array in struct C#

Tags: .net, visual-studio, c#-4.0

I 've problem with array in C#. I'm quite new in C# I'm used to do programs in java.
I'm trying to transfer this code from C++ to C#.
This is code in C++

```
typedef struct point_3d {           // Structure for a 3-dimensional point (NEW)
    double x, y, z;
} POINT_3D;

typedef struct bpatch {             // Structure for a 3rd degree bezier patch (NEW)
    POINT_3D    anchors[4][4];          // 4x4 grid of anchor points
    GLuint      dlBPatch;               // Display List for Bezier Patch
    GLuint      texture;                // Texture for the patch
} BEZIER_PATCH;
```

I have struct Vector3 in C# which is float x,y,z (I don't need double ...)
Now I'm trying to make structure bpatch and I have problems with the declaration of array

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct BPatch
{
  Vector3[][] anchors = new Vector3[4][4]; //there is the problem
  uint dblPatch; // I'll probably have to change this two lines but it doesn't matter now
  uint texture; 

}
```

what do I do wrong?? I need aray 4x4 in structure, its type should be structure Vector3 which is declared as float x, float y, float z.
Thanks

Comment: What makes you think that the C++ `POINT_3D` translates to the .NET `Vector3`?

Comment: Why not? I work according this tutorial from NEHE http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/bezier_patches__fullscreen_fix/18003/

and point3D has coordinates x,y,z and Vector3 I mentioned is ready to use in library which made gave to us our teacher at university, also with operations add and others.. so I used it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C#, Vector3[][] is not a matrix but an array of arrays. So, you will need to do this:

```
anchors = new Vector3[4][];
for(var i=0;i<anchors.Length;i++)
    anchors[i] = new Vector3[4];
```

Here's some documentation from msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx

Another way, inline:

```
Vector3[][] anchors = new Vector3[][]{new Vector3[4],new Vector3[4],new Vector3[4],new Vector3[4]};
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
Vector3[,] anchors = new Vector3[4,4];
```

Comment: Exactly! that's a matrix in c#