# cannot have instance field initializers in struct

Tags: .net, visual-studio, c#-4.0

I'm not so experienced in C#, I'm used to work in java. I've already asked for something before and some people advised me this.
link to my old topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689044/array-in-struct-c-sharp) 
But I have new problem with this code. The Visual Studio says that "I cannot have instance filed initializers in struct" - so there is some problem but I really don't understand this thing so is somehow possible make this work??
I just need anchors type Vector3 which is matrix or array of arrays - whatever 4x4
In java I'll probably write it 
public Vector3[][] = new Vector3[4][4];

This is my problematic code:

```
  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct BPatch
    {
        public Vector3[][] anchors = new Vector3[][] {new Vector3[4],new Vector3[4],new Vector3[4],new Vector3[4]};
        public uint dlBPatch;// Display list
        public uint texture;// Texture
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of ["cannot have instance field initializers in structs" problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406178/cannot-have-instance-field-initializers-in-structs-problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the time you've got 5 arrays, you might as well just make it a class. It will behave more sensibly:

```
class BPatch
{
    private readonly Vector3[][] anchors = new Vector3[][] {new Vector3[4],new Vector3[4],new Vector3[4],new Vector3[4]};
    public Vector3[][] Anchors { get { return anchors; } }
    public uint DlBPatch {get;set;}
    public uint Texture {get;set;}
}
```

If you have **good reason** to micro-optimize, a "fixed" array (rather than a jagged array) might be interesting.

Comment: And if I also need to set the anchors??
Why you used readonly??

I really don't much uderstand difference between fixed and jagged array. I found out that jagged array is array of array - thats only I know.

Comment: @user1097772 fixed sized arrays (fixed buffers) are an advanced technique in structs using "unsafe" code to embed a buffer *directly* in a struct. Hardcore stuff. You could make the outer array read-write. But in most cases that is an error; the intent is usually to change the *contents*, not to reassign the array. It is your type - do as you will. I should also add: most times, when someone new to c# uses a struct, they use it both inappropriately and incorrectly. Just saying...

Comment: Thx.
I just need to do this:
Bpatch bpatch = new Bpatch();
bpatch.anchors[0][1] = new Vector3(-0.75f,-0.75f,-0.5f);
bpatch.anchors[0][2] = new Vector3(-0.25f,-0.75f,0.0f);
etc..
Is that possible with readonly qualifier?
My first intent was have anchors as matrix 4x4

Comment: @user1097772 yes; that doesn't **reassign** the array - should work fine